# Chrome extension restarting every click

Tags: google-chrome

I make an exchange extension but I have some problems.

When I click extension icon My extension is working fine (expect close the app) but when I close and open again, my extension is restarting.

My code get data from another URL every open and close activity.

But I want this: my code must working on background and when I open the app, I need to see instant values.

Here is the manifest file:

```
{
"name" : "Eklenti",
"version" : "2.0",
"manifest_version" : 2,
"description" : "Bu bir google chrome eklentisidir.",
"browser_action" : {
  "default_icon" : "icon.png",
  "default_popup" : "index.html"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": [
     "background.js"
  ]
},
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "bootstrap.min.css","jquery-3.3.1.min.js","bootstrap.min.js","main.js" ],
  "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  }],

  "permissions": [ "contentSettings","activeTab","webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "debugger",
    "storage"]
}
```

Comment: External paste links are not good for this site. Questions should be stand-alone. Please [edit] this question and show relevant details.

Comment: What is an "exchange extension"? See [ask]. The idea is you take your time to explain what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Assume no one really knows what you are talking about and are too busy to figure it out.